# Has non-orthogonal CI (NOCI) been implemented in PySCF?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, electronic-structure, ab-initio-calculations, pyscf, configuration-interaction

I'm kinda new to Pyscf and was wondering if there is a way to do non-orthogonal CI calculations with it. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: It's available in OpenMolcas. Why does it have to be in PySCF for you?

Comment: It does't need to be pyscf. I just started using for pyscf for q. chemistry calculations and I wondered if there was a way to implement noci in it.

Comment: I didn't see your response because you didn't ping me with the `@` character.

Answer (score 3):

## NOCI is not available in the main branch of PySCF

That is why [your question on the PySCF GitHub page](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/issues/1697) which you asked on the same day as this question (next time please let us know if you are "cross-posting" a question!) was tagged by James Smith with the "feature-request" tag (it means that PySCF does ***not*** currently have NOCI as a feature).

If you want to implement NOCI in PySCF by yourself, it will probably be a big task for you if you don't have experience with writing electronic structure software (this is the type of thing that forms a substantial part of masters theses or elite undergrad theses, so it's not something that is done overnight for someone asking a question like this).

If you do want to implement it yourself, the answers on the GitHub page did give you some advice, which I'll summarize here:

- Once you have a way to generate non-orthogonal determinants, you can use [this Python interface to libgnme](https://github.com/BoothGroup/pygnme) to evaluate non-orthogonal matrix elements, for example $\langle D_i|H | D_j  \rangle$ for single-excitations.
- The libgnme GitHub page suggests the following papers for further reading (both by Hugh Burton):

  - [Generalized nonorthogonal matrix elements: Unifying Wick’s theorem and the Slater–Condon rules](https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jcp/article/154/14/144109/199579/Generalized-nonorthogonal-matrix-elements-Unifying),
  - [Generalized nonorthogonal matrix elements. II: Extension to arbitrary excitations](https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jcp/article/157/20/204109/2842193/Generalized-nonorthogonal-matrix-elements-II).

On the other hand, the free and open source software OpenMolcas can already do NOCI.

###### Also, after I wrote this answer, it was brought to my attention that [someone has indeed implemented NOCI in PySCF](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/issues/1697#issuecomment-1760824474) but it is not yet merged into the main PySCF branch.